# Compound key in Realm with lazy property

Tags: swift, realm, compound-key

I found this great solution for using Realm with compound primary key in Swift: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1192

```
public final class Card: Object {
  public dynamic var id = 0 {
      didSet {
          compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
      }
  }
  public dynamic var type = "" {
      didSet {
          compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
      }
  }
  public dynamic lazy var compoundKey: String = self.compoundKeyValue()
  public override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "compoundKey"
  }

  private func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
      return "\(id)-\(type)"
  }
}
```

But I discovered that Realm does not support lazy properties, in my case I receive this error:

> exception NSException *   name: "RLMException" - reason: "Lazy managed property 'compoundKey' is not allowed on a Realm Swift object class. Either add the property to the ignored properties list or make it non-lazy."  0x00007f8a05108060

Is it still possible to have compound key without lazy property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution you found is outdated. I'll leave a note about that there. I'd suggest removing the `lazy` modifier and initializing `compoundKey` to an empty string.