# How can I use a lazy var in Swift and Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, realm, dynamic-variables

I have a lazy var in Swift like:

```
import Realm

class DataUser: RLMObject {

@objc dynamic lazy var id: String = self.myId()

@objc dynamic var firstTime: Int = 0

@objc dynamic var position: Int = 0

private func myId() -> String {
        return “\(firstTime)\(position)”
}
```

I’m getting this message:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Lazy managed property 'id' is not allowed on a Realm Swift object
>   class. Either add the property to the ignored properties list or make
>   it non-lazy.'

What is the correct way to use a lazy-variable in Swift and Realm?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010548/compound-key-in-realm-with-lazy-property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compound key in Realm with lazy property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010548/compound-key-in-realm-with-lazy-property)

Comment: The suggested duplicate doesn't actually answer the question of how to ignore a managed property (or make it non managed), but rather deals with compound properties, which this doesn't seem to be.

Comment: override getter for your id and make it lazy

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `ignoreProperties()` method for creating lazy var

Swift code:

```
public override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
      return ["data"]
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use *dynamic lazy var id: String = self.myId()* also, and I don't think that your implementation is wrong. But Realm seems to not handling properly as  your *id* is lazy. you can see [bug report](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3337) about the same also.